# how to automate kendo date picker controls using protractor tool?

Tags: protractor

I am trying to write an automation script to validate Kendo Date picker control but it's not sending the value as expected format.

**Automation Script**

```
 describe('Submit a form with date values ', function () {
        it('Should submit a form after entering all the required fields', function () {

           var date_picker = element(by.xpath("//ca-datepicker[@name='enterDate']//input‌​")); 
            date_picker.sendKeys("01/01/2015);

        }

 }
```

**Result**
It's sending the value as 05/day/2015

**HTML:**

```html
<html>

<body>
  <ca-datepicker class="ca-datepicker ca-validation ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" _ngcontent-c23="" name="enterDate" required="" validatemin="">
    <kendo-datepicker class="ca-datepicker__input k-widget k-datepicker k-header ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
      <!---->
      <span class="k-picker-wrap k-state-default">
    <kendo-dateinput class="k-widget k-dateinput">
    <!---->
    <span class="k-dateinput-wrap">
    <input class="k-input" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" role="spinbutton" spellcheck="false" title="" tabindex="2" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" aria-valuetext=""/>
    <!---->
    </span>
      </kendo-dateinput>
      <span class="k-select" role="button" title="Toggle calendar" aria-label="Toggle calendar" aria-controls="01109451-42bb-40a9-abb4-fc148dca7114">
    <span class="k-icon k-i-calendar"/>
    </span>
      </span>
      <!---->
      <!---->
    </kendo-datepicker>
    <!---->
  </ca-datepicker>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Could you post your code through editing this question?

Answer (score 0):

Try it at the `input` level instead:

```
var date_picker = element(by.class('k-input'));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Always set date as current date so that test will always run properly in future as well.**

```
// get today's date
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if(dd<10) {
    dd='0'+dd
} 

if(mm<10) {
    mm='0'+mm
} 

today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;

date_picker.clear();
date_picker.sendKeys(today);
```